# How to fix the Rendered more hooks than during the previous render using react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

***index.tsx***

```
   import useUser from '@services/users';
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

function App() {
      const { t } = useTranslation();
    
      const { getAll } = useUser();
      const [ rowData, setRowData ] = useState([]);
    
     useEffect(() => {
        let ignore = false;
        (async function setAllData() {
          let response = await getAll({ length: 9999 });
        })()
        if (!ignore) {
            setRowData(response['data']['data']);
          }
        })()
        return () => {
          ignore = true;
        }
      }, [])
    
     return (
        <>
          <button>{t('create')}</button>
          {
            rowData.map((item, index) => (
              <div key={index}>
                {item.firstName}<br/>
              </div>
            ))
          }
        </>
      )
    }
    export default App;
```

***user.tsx***

```
export default function useUser() {
 const creds = useCredentials();

  Axios.defaults.baseURL = serverConfig[creds.server].api;
  
  return {

    getAll: (params?: object) => Axios.get(API_URL + (params ? getQueryParams(params) : ''))
    }

    }
```

I'm having trouble when I added the `react-i18next` which is the useTranslation. The error message is Rendered more hooks than during the previous render. when added the translation. How do I fix on it?

[image]

Comment: Is this the complete code? The error message usually indicates that you are conditionally calling a react hook.

Comment: The code you have posted does not contain the part that's causing it.

Comment: @trixn yes, when I try to remove the  ```useTranslation()``` which is the ```react-i18next```  there's no error. but I need to use the useTranslation

Comment: Which version of react are you using?

Comment: @trixn ```17.0.1```

Comment: `useEffect` / `useAnyHook` need to be inside a function. I don't use Next.js, but I've a feeling it must be auto-wrapping your code into a function that returns JSX if it's not causing an error on that return,.  So I would suggest wrapping the code you have got, into another function were `useEffect` etc can be seen to be run in order, in case next.js has some sort of mounting side effects.

Comment: Is it possible that it will cause on the ```setRowData```?

Comment: @Keith That is a lot of guessing. Next.js doesn't do any of that.

Comment: @trixn   Yes, was trying to figure out how the invalid JS syntax was even working.  The OP has now added the missing code, so now makes more sense.

Comment: I think that the "problematic" code is not pasted here. There error tells that in a first render there were found two calls to useContext but in the next render there was just one (and a call to useState). Could it be a problem with useUser? Could you try to comment this line (and the related code) to test it?

Comment: @VirgilioGM when I try to comment the setRowData there's no error.

Comment: @Beginner-Coder Surely there is no error because, if you don't update the state variable, the component is not rerendering. The error occurs when calling useContext inconsistently and, in the code I can see, I think it could only be related to the hook useUser

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with useTranslation.
For me the cause was wrapping the i18next init script in a function calling that inside App.tsx instead of just exporting i18n and importing it directly inside index.tsx

So NOT:

```
App.tsx

import initI18n from './i18n.ts'

const App = () => {
  initI18n()
  return <div>Party</div>
}
```

BUT THIS WORKED

```
index.tsx

import './i18n.ts'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```